# PHP no output from preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using `preg_replace()` as in the following code.

```
$p = preg_replace('/#[\d\w]+/', '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/search/term:'.str_replace('#', rawurlencode('%23'), '${1}').'">${1}</a>', $p);
$p will be a string like '(#ben)'
```

However, nothing is output using `$1`. Am I using `$1` incorrectly?

Should output this: `<h2>Bens (<a href="http://example.com/search/term:#ben">ben</a>) cat</h2>`

Comment: if $1 returns nothing, no match is found. Is your regex correct?

Comment: Could you please detail what the code is *supposed* to do?  What is the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a capturing group to reference back reference `$1`:

```
preg_replace('/(#[\d\w]+)/', ... 
               ^        ^
```

See it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/ThGru7).